# ASP.NET single page authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, authorization

I have an ASP.NET application where most of the pages are accessible to all authenticated users via a single sign on module that sets the username into the Session array variable. Now I have one folder A containing one page B.aspx and a list of usernames who are allowed to access this page B.aspx.

My question: how do I elegantly authorize only these users for this one page, or better, for this one folder. Can it be done with the location tag in a Web.config file inside folder A ? If so, how do I connect that config with custom code to check whether the username stored in the session variable is one of the authorized for that folder or page ? Can I use a custom membershipprovider ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

First, you scrap the kludged security methodology, as user name in a session cookie is not a good way to handle this. Okay, maybe a bit too overboard, as low security may be fine for you. If so, you can write a custom handler for the page that examines user name and compares to an updateable list.

NEW: With Session object, you are a bit more security, as the session token is sent over and the name is kept in session, but the Membership bits (below) handle translation of a particular session to a user without rewriting with your custom "this user is using this session" methodology. Yeah, ultimately you can argue Microsoft does something very similar to your software, but you leave the maintenance to them.

Going back to my original direction, there is the concept of roles and membership built into ASP.NET. If you use these bits, you can security trim the page (or even better folder so you can additional pages) to certain users (not as good) or roles (better) by setting up a new web.config with the security constraints.

The cool thing about the built in stuff is you can declaratively set up security and have the pipeline determine whether a user is valid or not without any heavy lifting on your part.

There is plenty of information on Membership and Roles on the various ASP.NET oriented sites.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean session cookie, but rather the server side session object. Also, all the online documentation I found used forms for authentication. My authentication is already taken care of by an external module, hence my post on this site looking for solutions...

Comment: That was my bad. Added a bit. It is still a core concept of buy versus build, even if "price" is $0, like .NET (can argue whether it is free, as in beer, or free, as in speech, later ;-)). The issue with the session variable is you have to control the security bits yourself. Not done correctly, you end up with hard coding. Another thing, it is more difficult to handle specific configs for a page folder yourself, while Membership has it built in. And, you can trim menus if you use sitemap, so users without permission don't have the option in their menu. And, you don't have to write that code.

Answer (score 0):

that can be achieved specifying the user's name that can access the directory separate by commas.

Comment: <location path="pathName">
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow users="matthew,sarah" />
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>

Comment: Thanks Nudier. I had already gotten that far. Where I'm stuck is how to take control of the mechanism that decides whether the current user is one of the names in the list, since this information is stored in the server's session object.

Answer (score 0):

As your username is not defined in web.config rather defined in some session variable you have to create a Form   Authentication Ticket for this e.g.

```
FormsAuthenticationSupport formsAuthenticationSupport = new FormsAuthenticationSupport();
formsAuthenticationSupport.SignIn(UsernameInSession, RoleName, true);
```

Now you can set authentication rules and location tag in web.config for UsernameInSession.